# Copying file from desktop to remote repository on SVN

Tags: linux, macos, svn

I am extremely new to SVN, I am using SVN on Mac OS terminal. I have a file on my laptop that I want to transfer to my repository on my remote server.

This is what I have done:

1. I have checked out the repository. It says "checked out revision *".
2. I have used cd until the folder that I want to insert the file. So at this point I have a path like: (...../src/soln$) so I want to insert the file in the 'soln' folder.

When I try:

1. `svn add ('...../lo.java')` (the path to my file on my computer) it says:

   > ('....../src/soln/') is not a working copy
2. `svn import ...../lo.java` it brought something weird to the screen

Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong or not doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that the parent is not yet in svn. Try to `svn add` each folder above lo.java.

As an example if the repo root is at `/path/to/my/repo` and your file is in `/path/to/my/repo/src/soln/lo.java` then you'll not only want to `svn add lo.java` from inside the soln directory, but you'll also want to `svn add /path/to/my/repo/src` and then `svn add /path/to/my/repo/src/soln` before you can perform the `svn add lo.java`